# A question on the implicit function theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

The question is given below:

Approximate by a second-degree polynomial the solution of $z^3 + 3xyz^2 - 5x^2y^2z + 14 = 0$, for $z$ as a function of $x,y,$ near (1, -1, 2).

Could anyone give me a hint for the solution please?

**My ideas:**

our desired function will map (x,y) to z, so $n=2$ and $m = 1$. further $x_{0} = (1, -1)$ and $y_{0} = 2$, and $F(x,y,z) = z^3 + 3xyz^2 - 5x^2y^2z + 14.$ clearly $F$ has a continuous partial derivative and the derivative is $$DF(x,y,z)[3yz^2 -10xy^2z \quad 3xz^2-10x^2yz \quad 3z^2+6xyz-5x^2y^2  ],$$

And hence,

$$DF(1,-1,2)=[-32 \quad 32 \quad -5  ],$$

Then,

$$DF(1,-1,2)\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0  \\
z
\end{bmatrix}= -5z,$$

But then what next?

Comment: Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: okay I will do so @5xum

Comment: I am editing my question @5xum

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the derivative of $F$. The steps I suggest you take are the following:

1. We know, from the implicit function theorem, that, near the point $(1, -1)$, there exists a function $z:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R$ such that $$z(x,y)^3 + 3xyz(x,y)^2 - 5x^2y^2z(x,y) + 14 = 0.$$ That is, in this step, we write $z$ as the function. We also know, of course, that $z(1,-1)=2$.
2. Now, take the equation above, and take the derivative, with respect to $x$, of it. Be careful: $z$ is a function of $x$ now, but $y$ is not! So, $\frac{\partial z(x,y)^3}{\partial x} = 3z(x,y)^2\cdot \frac{\partial z(x,y)}{\partial x}$, for example.
3. From the point above, you should get an equation from which you can extract the value of $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ at $(x,y)=(1,-1)$.
4. Do the same to get the partial derivative for $y$.

Comment: And how can I approximate by a second degree polynomial the solution of the given equation at the given point?

Comment: @hopefully https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Taylor's_theorem_for_multivariate_functions

Comment: yes I heard certainly of it ..... but at which step shall I use it?

Comment: @hopefully Well, to use it, you need to know the partial derivatives of $z$ with respect to $x$ and $y$ are equal to. Once you have them, the taylor series, cut of at the right point, will give you the approximate polynomial.

Comment: what do you mean by "are equal to" do you mean that I will find the partial derivative of z w.r.t x and y ..... and do you mean by "cut at the right point" at (1.-1.2)?

Comment: I have calculated the derivative to guarantee that the function $z \rightarrow DF(1,-1,2)(0,0,z)$ is a bijection so I can apply the Implicit function theorem.

Comment: I'm sorry, but it appears to me that you are not really reading what I am writing and I am no longer interested in this question. I specifically said you don't need the derivative of $F$. What you need are the partial derivatives. Good luck.

Comment: I am so sorry @5xum

Comment: the last question ..... to what function am I writing the polynomial of degree 2?